# GCC options for optimization on given CPU architecture

Tags: c, gcc, x86, intel, compiler-optimization

I am working on Nehalam/westmere Intel micro architecture CPU. I want to optimize my code for this Architecture. Are there any specialized compilation flags or C functions by GCC which will help me improve my code's run time performance?

I am already using `-O3`.

```
Language of the Code - C
Platform - Linux
GCC Version - 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC)
```

In my code I have some floating point comparison and they are done over a million time.

Please assume the code is already best optimized.

Comment: What's wrong with the results you get by looking at the documentation and Googling?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: @jthill was not able to get any thing for this perticular architecture .. so i was just wondering if we have anything specific like intel compilers

Comment: @jthill - I arrived to this question via Google

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Warning: **the answer is incorrect**.

<s>You can actually analyze all disabled and enabled optimizations yourself. Run on your computer:</s>

```
gcc -O3 -Q --help=optimizers | grep disabled
```

And then read about the flags that are still disabled and can according to  [the gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html) influence performance.

Answer (score 21):

First, if you really want to profit from optimization on newer processors like this one, you should install the newest version of the compiler. 4.4 came out some years ago, and even if it still seems maintainted, I doubt that the newer optimization code is backported to that. (Current version is 4.7)

Gcc has a catch-all optimization flag that usually should produce code that is optimized for the compilation architecture: `-march=native`. Together with `-O3` this should be all that you need.

Comment: If you're not building for your host, you can use `-march=nehalem`, `-march=sandybridge`, `-march=haswell`, `-march=bdver1` (Bulldozer), `-march=bdver3` (Steamroller), `-march=silvermont`, etc. etc.  Use `-mtune` to tune for a certain CPU without using instruction-set extensions that will fault on older CPUs.  For example `-march=nehalem -mtune=haswell` is a shorthand for `-msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mtune=haswell`

Comment: In contrast to `-mtune=cpu-type`, which merely tunes the generated code for the specified `cpu-type`, `-march=cpu-type` allows GCC to generate code that may not run at all on processors other than the one indicated.

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to add an `-march=...` option. The `...` should be replaced with whatever is closest to your CPU architecture (there tend to be minor differences) described [in the i386/x86_64 options for GCC here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options).

I would use `core2` because `corei7` (the one you'd want) is only available in GCC 4.6 and later. See the [arch list for GCC 4.6 here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options).

Comment: The weird and obscure `corei7` and `corei7-avx` naming is no longer necessary; later GCC versions allow `-march=nehalem`, `-march=skylake` and so on.  (Same for `-mtune`).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a gcc so old that it doesn't support corei7, you could use -mtune=barcelona